# Why is the retrieveuser method in DaoAuthenticationProvider calling passwordencoder in UsernameNotFoundException catch?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I looked at the source for `DaoAuthenticationProvider` and I found something that looked strange to me, in the `retrieveUser` method.

If the `userDetailService` throws a `UserNameNotFoundException`, the following code is in the `catch`:

```
catch (UsernameNotFoundException notFound) {
        if (authentication.getCredentials() != null) {
            String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
            passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(userNotFoundEncodedPassword,
                    presentedPassword, null);
        }
        throw notFound;
    }
```

I fail to see why it calls the `passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid`. It doesn't use it for anything, then throws the exception up in the chain again. From what I know, the `passwordencoder` doesn't throw any exceptions, it returns a `boolean` (which, again, doesn't seem to be used for anything).

Anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [SEC-2056](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2056):

> Spring Security's DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticates users by utilizing the PasswordEncoder interface to compare the submitted password with the actual password. If a user is not found, the comparison is skipped which, depending on the PasswordEncoder implementation, can result in a significant difference in the amount of time required to attempt to authenticate an actual user versus a user that does not exist. This opens up the possibility of a side channel attack that would enable a malicious user to determine if a username is valid.
>
> [...]
>
> **Fix:**
>
> DaoAuthenticationProvider now performs PasswordEncoder.isPasswordValid when a user is not found.

See also: [SEC-2608](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2608)

Comment: Hey Dur, thanks for the quick response, makes total sense now that i've read it :) Looking at SEC-2608, you could argue that a small java comment could have been warranted at that row!